# jQuery Validation Plugin and Error Placement Issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am currently using the jquery validation plugin that can be found at: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. I have been searching google and am having issues figuring out how to make the error appear in the textbox that triggers the error on submit. I am open to using a different plug-in if this result can be achieved in a much simpler manner.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you mean dispay the error inside textbox as value???

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So...completely nuke the value the user entered, not giving them a chance to fix it?

Comment: Not to mention inject new values that may actually pass as real data, filling your entire system with error messages instead of usernames?

Comment: you can write you own validation and add atribute as placeholder when there is an error if you are using HTML5

Comment: Well ideally what I wanted to do was to create custom error handlers for each input and then when the form is submitted a box would open in colorbox with the errors being displayed in a more descriptive manner and then the user could close the colorbox and go back to the form and fix their errors. The person who originally made the website made it using javascript and loaded each page the dynamically into a div so it has caused me to get creative with getting around this issue. The way the form currently works is it checks through javascript on submit then uses ajax to submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call the error placement function:

```
    

    $("#form_id").validate({
        rules: {
            field: { required: true, email: true }
        },
        messages: {
            field: { required: "" , email: ""}
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr("id") == "field_id") {
                $('#target_error_placement_id').html(error);
            }
         }
    });
```

Is that your problem?

Comment: Also, if you want to display add a red border to the textbox with the error you can add the following to your css: .error { border:1px solid red; }